# How to stream a specific microphone through a Discord bot using Discord.js?

Tags: node.js, discord.js, audio-streaming

I am trying to create a bot to stream a specific audio input device of my pc. I was able to successfully connect to a voice chat but I couldn't find a way to list my audio input devices and stream a specific one of them.
Here's my code:

```js
const Discord = require('discord.js');
const client = new Discord.Client();
const {token} = require('./secret.json');
const {prefix}  = require('./config.json');
//const broadcast = client.createVoiceBroadcast();

client.on('ready', () => {
  console.log(`Logged in as ${client.user.tag}!`);
});

client.on('message', msg => {
  if (msg.content === `${prefix}summon`) {
        msg.member.voiceChannel.join()
            .then(connection => {
                console.log('Streaming audio.');
                // should stream one of my mics
            }).catch(console.error);
  } else if (msg.content === `${prefix}unsummon`){
        client.leaveVoiceChannel(mesg.member.voiceStat.channelID);
    }
});

client.login(token);
```

Comment: Did you figure out how to go about this?

Comment: Hey, sorry for the delay. I didn't notice the notification. I didn't figure it out yet, but I also didn't try any further since I asked. Maybe the answer below would work for you.

Answer (score 0):

You'll have to create a `readableStream` and use `connection.playStream()` to pipe the data to your voice channel. Since Discord.js doesn't have a native way to do this, you'll have to use another node module. 
https://www.npmjs.com/package/microphone-stream might be of some use